# What is the alternative to MilRelease api from MilCore.dll?

Tags: wpf, winapi, windows-7, splash-screen

Hi I am trying to port my application from windows Vista to Windows 7. 
In my WPF application I am showing a splash screen, for which I have used WIC components. 
I am creating some resources using

IWICImagingFactory_CreateDecoderFromStream_Proxy
IWICImagingFactory_CreateFormatConverter_Proxy
CreateBitmapFlipRotator

And then to release these resource I am calling

MILRelease(void *Unknown)

In Windows 7 MilCore.dll has been removed from Windows 7 and the MILRelease is part of milcore.dll. What is is the alternate api which I can use?

Comment: Why can't you use the actual WIC APIs (like IWICImagingFactory::CreateDecoderFromStream (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee690309(VS.85).aspx)?

Comment: I am not sure, this code was already written. I am just trying to port it to windows 7. One thing is that the code is written C# and using PInvoke the api have been called. I am not sure if PInvoke has anything to do with these functions being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resources created by

IWICImagingFactory_CreateDecoderFromStream_Proxy 
 IWICImagingFactory_CreateFormatConverter_Proxy
 CreateBitmapFlipRotator

Can be released using Marshal::Release()

For more details check out.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.release.aspx